# My PHP Contact from is sending Blank messages to me

Tags: php, html

```
HTML:
<form class="contact_form" action="php/mail.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="name">Name*</label>
                                    <input type="text"  placeholder="Your Name" required />
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <label for="name">Email*</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" required />
                                    <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <label for="name">Website</label>
                                    <input type="url" name="website" placeholder="Your website" required pattern="(http|https)://.+"/>
                                    <span class="form_hint">Proper format "http://someaddress.com"</span>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <label for="message">Message:</label>
                                    <textarea rows="6" cols="40" name="message" ></textarea>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <button class="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </form>
```

HTML

/* Subject and Email Variables */

```
$emailSubject = 'Contact Form';
$webMaster = 'email@address.com';

/* Gathering Data Variables */

$nameField = $_POST['Name'];
$emailField = $_POST['Email'];
$website = $_POST['Website'];
$messageField = $_POST['Message'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $nameField <br>
Email: $emailField <br>
Message: $messageField <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

/* Results Rendered as HTML */
```

Comment: Can you out please the message you got ?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: in `$headers` is undefined `$email` variable. Can you post HTML form too?

Comment: please post your form code..

Answer (score 1):

I think you got typo there, change

```
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
```

to

```
$headers = "From: $emailField\r\n";
```

Remember to validate the $emailField to avoid injections!

Update: Now that I can see the actual HTML for the form, there is some problems.

I think `for` requires and ID field, so you should add one to every field in the form.

You also forgot to set `name` in the name text field.

Lets add the `name` attribute in the name field, and add the `ID` field (which should be done for the other fields also):

```
<label for="name">Name*</label>
<input type="text"  placeholder="Your Name" required />
```

to

```
<label for="name">Name*</label>
<input type="text"  id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required />
```

`$_POST['Name']` is case-sensetive, so you should change your code so the variables match the names in the html.
example:

```
$nameField = $_POST['Name'];
```

should be

```
$nameField = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: If you use the user-supplied variable, you should add that this value needs to be validated / filtered to avoid header injection.

Answer (score 1):

There are more problems, so:

1. you missed `name` attribute at the name text input
2. you used incorect names, PHP is case-sensitive in keys (`$_POST['name'] !== $_POST['Name']`). This is the point why you received blank meesages
3. `for` attribute in labels has to correspond with input `ID`

Updated code:

```
<form class="contact_form" action="php/mail.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="Name">Name*</label>
            <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Your Name" required />
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="Email">Email*</label>
            <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Your email address" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="Website">Website</label>
            <input type="url" id="Website" name="Website" placeholder="Your website" required pattern="(http|https)://.+"/>
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "http://someaddress.com"</span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="Message">Message:</label>
            <textarea rows="6" id="Message" cols="40" name="Message" ></textarea>
        </li>

        <li>
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

put `$nameField = $_POST['Name'];
$emailField = $_POST['Email'];
$website = $_POST['Website'];
$messageField = $_POST['Message'];` within a post function. After verifying `$_post` is not empty. on form submit.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. It was the ID's that I didnt have in my code.. I appreciate this very much.